# How to store and write the Vlookup results in VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm getting mad with Vlookup in VBA! 
Scenario: 
I have two sheets: MySheet and OtherSheet. 
The look for value: column ID_Consegna in MySheet
Range where to search: matrice in OtherSheet
indexes: 6 and 7 (so I need to obtain two values)

I must then write these values obtained from the formula in column G and H of MySheet.

the code I have done till now is:

```
Sub cerca_vert()

'definisco il foglio attivo
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = Worksheets("data")
Set otherSheet = Worksheets("data (2)")
mySheet.Activate

'definisco la colonna ID_Consegna
Dim cella_indirizzo As Variant

Dim lLastRow As Long
lLastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
Dim ID_Consegna As Variant
ID_Consegna = mySheet.Range("F2:F" & lLastRow)


'definisco la matrice di ricerca nel secondo foglio "data (2)"
Dim val1_cap As Integer
Dim val2_citta As Variant

Dim lLastRow_matrice As Long
lLastRow_matrice = otherSheet.Cells(otherSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Dim matrice As Variant
matrice = otherSheet.Range("D2:I" & lLastRow)

For Each cella_indirizzo In ID_Consegna
    On Error Resume Next
    val1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(cella_indirizzo), matrice, 6, False)
    val2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(cella_indirizzo), matrice, 7, False).Value
Next cella_indirizzo
End Sub
```

my questions are:

1. Why val1 and val2 remain empty?
2. How could I "fill" them?

how could I "fill" them?

many thanks to anyone who will help me!

Comment: 1. you did not dim `otherSheet` 2.`ID_Consegna` is a range not a variant and must be set as well 3.`matrice` is a range not a variant

Comment: There are only 6 columns in your range, you are vlooking the 6th and 7th column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are lokking to get the results from Column F and G then

```
Sub cerca_vert()

'definisco il foglio attivo
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet, OtherSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cella_indirizzo As Range    ' in loop
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim ID_Consegna As Range
    Dim val1, val2
    Dim lLastRow_matrice As Long
    Dim matrice As Range

    Set mySheet = Worksheets("data")
    Set OtherSheet = Worksheets("data (2)")

    'definisco la colonna ID_Consegna

    lLastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ID_Consegna = mySheet.Range("F2:F" & lLastRow)
    lLastRow_matrice = OtherSheet.Cells(OtherSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Set matrice = OtherSheet.Range("D2:I" & lLastRow)

    'definisco la matrice di ricerca nel secondo foglio "data (2)"

    For Each cella_indirizzo In ID_Consegna.Cells
        On Error Resume Next
        val1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(cella_indirizzo), matrice, 3, False)
        val2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(cella_indirizzo), matrice, 4, False)
        cella_indirizzo.Offset(, 1) = val1
        cella_indirizzo.Offset(, 2) = val2
    Next cella_indirizzo

End Sub
```

Comment: oh my God! it's days I'm looking at it and didn't spot that the indexes must be 5 and 6!!! thank you so much @Davesexcel! you made my week! the range I figured it out by myself, while I like your suggestion to write the values where I need. Thanks man! :)